# Honda Fit GP5 Hybrid battery not charging

Tags: honda, battery, hybrid

Last two days in my Honda Fit GP5 (2014, hybrid, 1490cc) I noticed engine isn't stop when car is in parking mode and hybrid battery meter doesn't get over 3/6 even though engine was on for half an hour (with A/C on in 30-32C outside). It happened only within last two days and when I'm driving car is running on EV mode properly and fuel consumption also OK for last two days. Is this indicates a hybrid system/battery fault?

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?  I suspect something similar in mine - also a 2014 1490cc GP5.   I did notice increased fuel consumption and it spending very little time in EV mode as well.

Comment: I believe my problem may have been a badly wired radio.